# Minecraft Bukkit plugin programming keep an java Object over Reload

Tags: bukkit

Is there any way to keep an Java Object over Reload? Without saving it to a txt or json. I mean that the object remains stored in RAM and remains retrievable.
I need that, because I program a plugin, which creates an Internet connection that should remain open during and after a reload.

Comment: I'm assuming your referring to /reload. You cannot keep something stored over reload without saving it somewhere due to the fact the reload is restarting your plugin completely and starting it again. I would be interested to hear why you're looking to do this, however.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep an Object after a server reload, you will need to save it to a file.

You should look into Object Serialization in terms of Bukkit to solve your problem. It will greatly simplify the process of storing an Object's "information" onto a file. This also connects with the Object Deserialization, which is just the process of taking that stored "information" from the file and re-adding it back into your plugin (program).

[Here is a post](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Configuration_API_Reference#Serializing_and_Deserializing_Objects) from the "BukkitWiki" that will introduce the topic to you.